# A value that need to be extended in time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

people.

I need to sum values of a data frame in different columns.

- **OUT** with the amount invested
- **IN** with the amount received
- **DRAW** with the amount taken.

So, **OUT** is the total invested. If you have a **DRAW**, means that value was taken for the investment.
As an example, -100 (LINE 1) + 100 (LINE 2[DRAW]) means that you took part of the investment. In this case, the value received in the column **IN**, means we have 110-100 (both in line 2. One in column **IN**, the other, in **DRAW**) of income, giving us a total income of 10 units (10% of the investment = (110-100)/100 = (IN-DRAW)/OUT).

We also could have a DRAW without a return, as in line 12. In this example, from this line on, the income will be calculate in 2x-200 (-400) + 20 = -380.

After line 5, we have an investment of 2 times -200; -400 in the total and no DRAWs and OUTs, until line 12.
My doubt lies in what is the best way to calculate the % in each month based on the OUTs, INs and DRAWs in all table.

| LINE | DATE | OUT | IN | DRAW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-20 | -100 | - |  |
| 2 | 2020-02-10 | - | 110 | 100 |
| 3 | 2020-02-11 | -200 | - |  |
| 4 | 2020-02-21 | - | 20 |  |
| 5 | 2020-02-25 | -200 | - |  |
| 6 | 2020-02-26 | -200 | - |  |
| 7 | 2020-02-26 | - | 20 |  |
| 8 | 2020-03-09 | - | 40 |  |
| 9 | 2020-04-01 | - | 10 |  |
| 10 | 2020-04-07 | - | 20 |  |
| 11 | 2020-04-10 | - | 10 |  |
| 12 | 2020-05-10 | - | - | 20 |

Answer (score 0):

I came with a solution, still not knowing if is the best one, but worked fine.
I made a new column join OUT and DRAW together (OUTDRAW).
This column was created with OUT data, and them filled the NaN spaces with DRAW values (this worked only because the values are not in the same line):

```
df['OUTDRAW'] = df['OUT']
df['OUTDRAW'].fillna(df['DRAW'], inplace=True)
```

After, filled NaN with 0 and made a cumsum on it.

```
df['OUTDRAW'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['OUTDRAW'].cumsum()
```

This gave me the column

| LINE | DATE | OUT | DRAW | OUTDRAW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-20 | -100 | - | -100 |
| 2 | 2020-02-10 | - | 100 | 0 |
| 3 | 2020-02-11 | -200 | - | -200 |
| 4 | 2020-02-21 | - | 20 | -200 |
| 5 | 2020-02-25 | -200 | - | -400 |
| 6 | 2020-02-26 | -200 | - | -600 |
| 7 | 2020-02-26 | - | 20 | -600 |
| 8 | 2020-03-09 | - | 40 | -600 |
| 9 | 2020-04-01 | - | 10 | -600 |
| 10 | 2020-04-07 | - | 20 | -600 |
| 11 | 2020-04-10 | - | 10 | -600 |
| 12 | 2020-05-10 | - | 20 | -580 |

So, now we have a column in time that can be used to calculate % in time.

Note: If you want to make it by month, first make a new column with the months (be careful with the years), group by it and them do the cumsum or your values will be calculate wrongly.